# How to make visual studio 2008 deploy to ftp in ACTIVE mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, ftp, amazon-ec2, publishing

I'm using Amazon EC2 services and would like to publish my WCF application to this server using the visual studio 2008. Instead of opening so many ports on the amazon firewall, I'll use the ftp ACTIVE mode which will need to open only two ports (20,21). Alas, visual studio 2008 is determine to use only PASSIVE ftp connection, why?!

Comment: BTW, as a workaround I use SMB to perform publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with VS 2008, I just did a workaround to use SMB to publish.

Answer (score 0):

FTP in active mode needs to open a connection back to you, and a lot of firewalls can't handle that. It certainly wouldn't fly in the corporate environment I work in. So passive mode tends to be easier to get working.

If VS has no option for changing this, I guess they went for the dumbed-down failsafe option. But I don't know VS, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: I managed to access my FTP by regular windows ftp CLI tool. The problem is with the VS that even have a check box for passive ftp mode, but for some reason it doesn't work...